# Tabulator formatter calculates percent of another column

Tags: javascript, tabulator

hopefully this is simple enough for me to not chuck Codepen etc up.

I'm trying to create a custom formatter/mutator in tabulator but I'm having difficulty grabbing the total of another column. *bottomCalc* isn't accessible and I don't understand how to access all the data from another column to run a loop through them.

| ID | Percent | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 25 | 10 |
| 2 | 12.5 | 5 |
| 3 | 12.5 | 5 |
| 4 | 50 | 20 |
| Total | 100 | 40 |

```
{title:"%", field:"calc-pct", sorter:"number", formatter:function(cell){
    let amt = cell.getRow().getCell("amount");
    let amtCol = cell.getRow().getColumn("amount");
    // loop through amount to get total here
        amtTotal += amt
    pct = amt / amtTotal
    return pct;
}},
```

The Tabulator docs are extensive and very helpful, but there's not a ton of info about using the getData(), getRow() stuff inside formatters/mutators - a lot of these seem to be more for external functions after the table has been built. Helpful stuff, but not for my case.

**EDIT:**

Didn't include this unfortunately, but in addition to getting this working, I need to be able to edit the *Amount* column and have the percent live update. I've posted the solution below so anybody else who's looking for this can hopefully have some help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with Michael's help, I managed to get this working. I had to analyse the table data a bit via the console but managed to get it working with the following. I'd imagine there's probably some inbuilt methods in Tabulator for accessing all the rows in the table but I couldn't figure it out with `getRow()` etc.

## The Formatter:

Runs on table load, initial population of pct fields.

```
let pctFormatter = function(cell){
    let amountColTotal = 0;
    cell.getTable().getData().forEach(row => { amountColTotal += parseFloat(row.amount); });
    console.log("Amount PCT col total: " + amountColTotal)
    let amount = cell.getRow().getCell("amount").getValue();
    console.log("Amount PCT: " + amount)
    return Math.round ( ( ( amount / amountColTotal ) * 100 ) * 10 ) / 10;
}
```

## The Mutator:

Runs on amount edit, loops through table data and setsValue on each cell in the `calc_pct` column, updating the values with the new pct figure.

```
export let pctMutatorRun = function(cell) { 
    cell.getRow().getCell("calc_srm").setValue(true);
    let table = cell.getTable()
    table.rowManager.rows.forEach(row => {
        console.log(row.getCell("calc_pct").setValue(true));
    });
```

## The Table:

```
{title:"%", field:"calc_pct", sorter:"number", formatter:pctFormatter},
{title:"Amt (kg)", field:"amount", editor:"input", sorter:"number", bottomCalc:"sum", cellEdited:pctMutatorRun, bottomCalcParams:{precision:3}},
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let amountColTotal = 0;
cell.getTable().getData().forEach(row => { amountColTotal += row.amount; });
```

This is very simplistic tho.

You could also use [getCalcResults()](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/column-calcs#results)

Comment: Cheers for this Michael, after a bit of testing, I've realised that very likely a mutator is more what I'm looking for as I'm wanting to be able to edit and live update the amount column, and have the pct column live update. To get me started, how does one loop through the tabular data (say, the amount column in my case) in a mutator. I've tried a bunch of combinations (`data.getTable()`; `value.getTable()`) and from what I understand, they're all working with the data in the background.

Comment: Problem is that from what I can see, I can access the row data, but not the rest of the table, or `getCalcResults()` data as they've not been run.

Comment: Updated my question to reflect what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a function which calculates the percentages (updatePercent in below example) on `dataLoaded` callback of the table and `cellEdited` callback of the column you want to edit to achieve what you are looking for:

```js
var updatePercent = async () => {
    await table.recalc();
  
  var sum = table.getCalcResults().bottom.amount;
  var data = table.getData('active');
  
  data.forEach(row => row.percent = (row.amount / sum) * 100);
  table.updateData(data);
}

var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
  height: '100%',
  layout: "fitColumns",
  dataLoaded: updatePercent,
  dataFiltered: updatePercent,
  columns: [{
      title: "Name",
      field: "name"
    },
    {
      title: "Percent",
      field: "percent",
      bottomCalc: "sum"
    },
    {
      title: "Amount",
      field: "amount",
      bottomCalc: "sum",
      editor: "input",
      headerFilter: true,
      cellEdited: updatePercent
    }
  ]
});

var tabledata = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Oli Bob",
    amount: 10
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Mary May",
    amount: 5
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Christine Lobowski",
    amount: 5
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Brendon Philips",
    amount: 20
  }
];

table.setData(tabledata);
```

```css
html,
body {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.tabulator {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, Apple Color Emoji, Segoe UI Emoji;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tabulator/4.9.3/css/bootstrap/tabulator_bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tabulator/4.9.3/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="example-table"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9n0fwz4e/

**Edit:**

With header filtering: h[ttps://jsfiddle.net/ox09p8Lq/](https://jsfiddle.net/ox09p8Lq/)

Comment: Updated my answer to include filtering after Michael O'Keefe's filtering suggestion. Thanks Michael.

Answer (score 0):

Heres a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7k468amL/) just in case you want to include filtering

```
comment.log("leave me alone Stackoverflow.com");
```

Comment: Thanks mate! Will compare the two methods when I get a moment. Doesn't tabulator have native column filtering?

Comment: not sure what you mean by native column filtering ? There are programmable filters and headerFilters. headerFilters are the easiest to do demonstrations with (like jsfiddle) but often they're quite simplistic (in this example, just straight "="). But the main point in your exercise is that not every row in the data is being shown/used for calculation, which affects the bottomCalc, and therefore affects your percentage column.

Comment: Cheers Michael - had another look and I think I'd assumed the filter function you'd put in there was non-built in, but it was just to update the table columns as well. Thanks mate!